422 Error with @jwt_required() in Flask App Deployed on VPS with Nginx
I'm facing an issue while deploying my Flask application on a VPS server with Nginx. The app works fine when tested locally and also when hosted on Heroku. However, when deployed on my VPS, any route protected by @jwt_required() throws a 422 error.
Server Setup:
Ubuntu VPS
Nginx as a reverse proxy
Flask Development Server to run the Flask app (just for test)
Flask-JWT-Extended for JWT authentication
What Works:
All API routes without the @jwt_required() decorator work perfectly.
The same application works as expected (even with @jwt_required()) when deployed on Heroku.
What Fails:
Any route using the @jwt_required() decorator on the VPS setup returns a 422 error.
Removing @jwt_required() allows the routes to work normally.
I suspect it might have something to do with Nginx configurations, but I can’t figure out what. Could it be related to how headers or JSON bodies are being handled by the server?
Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
